# VS2015 XAML editor: Closing tag is automatically deleted - how to prevent it?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

If I have the following structure:

```
<Border>
   <SomeControl />
</Border>
```

... and I close the Border element on the same line, by ending it with `/>`:

```
<Border />
   <SomeControl />
</Border>
```

... then the third line will be automatically deleted:

```
<Border />
<SomeControl />
</Border> the editor automatically deletes this line
```

How can this helpful thing be prevented from happening?

Comment: How is it a problem if it deletes orphaned, unmatched closing tags? Anyway, as with all VS text editor helpfulness, Ctrl+Z immediately after your own change will undo the "improvement".

Comment: It's not a problem, I find it helpful. so... How do I disable it ?

Comment: I can't find anything better than following the `/` with Ctrl+Z

Comment: @EdPlunkett There can be many lines between the two tags. So the automatic change will happen totally out of sight.

Comment: You don't have to see the closing tag. Visual Studio adds an undo object for whatever change you made to the text, followed by another undo object for the changes it makes in the course of reformatting. This includes deleting the orphaned close tag and unindenting the intervening content.